# How can I rewrite a 'subfolder' to a script?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect a URL `example.com/servers/1/` to a PHP script (`example.com/serverinfo.php`) that recieves the `1` part of the requested URL as a GET variable (or similar).

I currently have a rule `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php` that rewrites URLs such as `example.com/servers` to `example.com/[file].php`, and tried to base the following rule off that:

```
RewriteRule ^/?servers/([0-9]+)$/ /serverinfo.php$
```

The new rule has no effect (other than causing the page's CSS to fail to load), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# handle /servers/123
RewriteRule ^/?servers/([0-9]+)/?$ /serverinfo.php?num=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```